# Jetpack compose DESKTOP BasicTextField - how to Shift Enter to line skip

Tags: kotlin, compose-multiplatform

I'm trying to implement a messenger via Compose Desktop.

[image]

It looks like the image above.

I want to use the ENTER KEY to trigger send action, and use SHIFT + ENTER as a line skip command.

I've tried two attempts with no luck.

My first attempt - tried to use keyboard options, but didn't work.

```
BasicTextField(
                value = textFieldState,
                onValueChange = { input ->
                    textFieldState = input
                },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Send),
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onSend = {
                    mPresenter.sendTextMsg(textFieldState)
                    textFieldState = ""
                }),
                textStyle = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                    fontFamily = NotoSans,
                    color = Color.Black
                )
            )
```

Second attempt - tried to utilize onPreviewKeyEvent. Sending the message works, but line skip doesn't work.

```
BasicTextField(
                value = textFieldState,
                onValueChange = { input ->
                    textFieldState = input
                },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().onPreviewKeyEvent {
                    if (it.key == Key.Enter) {
                        if (it.isShiftPressed) {
                            textFieldState += ""
                        } else {
                            mPresenter.sendTextMsg(textFieldState)
                            textFieldState = ""
                        }
                        true
                    } else {
                        false
                    }
                },
                textStyle = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                    fontFamily = NotoSans,
                    color = Color.Black
                )
            )
```

Is there a way to implement such action?

Comment: Why `textFieldState += ""`? Maybe `textFieldState += "\n"`?

Comment: @bylazy it's a miss typing. +="\n" doesn't work as well.